# Update angular code to call api on a random timely manner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have the following code which calls an api which returns a color, and then it renders the color on a grid of boxes.

However, its too fast, and even with 5 server cluster, I am getting exceptions, this is for  a service fabric demo I am trying to build.

It looks its calling 500 times the service, then wait a random number of milliseconds and then call 500 times the api again.

I would like every set of 500 to be also random timed, in order to make the demo succesfully without the service going down.

```
angular.module('colorApp',[])
    .controller('ColorController',['$http', function($http){

        var vm = this;
        vm.blocks = [];

        for(var i=0;i<500; i++){
            var block ={
                updateColor: updateColor
            };

            block.updateColor(block);
            vm.blocks.push(block);
        }

        vm.blocks.forEach(function(block){
            var interval = Math.floor((Math.random()*5000)+1);
            //var interval = 5000;
            setInterval(function(){
                block.updateColor(block);
            }, interval)

        });

        function updateColor(item){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/color'
            }).then(function (response){
                item.color= response.data;
            })
        }


    }]);

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="colorApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0
        }
        .block{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 0px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            border: solid 1px #ffffff;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ColorController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="block in vm.blocks" class="block" ng-style="{'background-color':block.color}"></div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: right now you make 500 requests straight away and then set a random interval of 0-5 seconds for each of the requests, is this what you intended? and if so where exactly do you wish to add a random delay?

Comment: between each api rest call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wan't is a delay in execution for every http call you can simply wrap it in a timeout.

```
...

setInterval(function(){
  delayedUpdateColor(block);
}, interval);

...

function delayedUpdateColor(block) {
  var timeout = Math.floor((Math.random()*5000)+1); // choose your range...

  setTimeout(function() {
    block.updateColor(block);
  }, timeout);
}
```